# Ldap connection failed in php?

Tags: php, ldap

HI Am trying to connect and unbind  the server and port  ldap connection using php.

Here is my code:

```
$hostname = 'ldaps://www.google.com';
$port = 636;
echo "ldap check";
$lp = ldap_connect($hostname,$port);
echo "servername";
echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
if ($bind = @ldap_bind($lp, $username.$hostname, $password)){
    echo "Hello";
    ldap_unbind($lp,$username,$password);
}
```

Failure:

But am not connecting with the ldap connection.PLease help me to fix the code.

Comment: what is the error message that you are getting ?

Comment: am not getting any error message simply my page loads and it is not printing any error messages and unable to see others contents also@RamC

Answer (score 1):

When I read your code right, there are two issues:

1. The port you are giving will never be used in the `ldap_connect`. The docs clearly state that using the port as second argument to `ldap_connect` is deprecated and will only be used when you pass a servername or IP. But you are passing a URI, so that needs to include the port as well.
2. You are trying to bind as `$username . $hostname`. So you are tying to conntect 'someuser' as `someuserldaps://www.google.com` - I doubt that that will ever work. You probably want something like `someuser@www.google.com`...